# Enviar data entre dos metodos laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito enviar el post de la funcion store a edit pero la funcion edit no esta tomando el dato que necesito

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['nombre' => 'required', ]);
    $post = DirectorioDoctor::create([
        'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
    ]);
    error_log($post);
    return view('admin.directoriomedico.editdirectorio', $post);
}

public function edit(DirectorioDoctor $post){
    error_log($post);
    return "Estra a edit" . $post;
    //return view('admin.directoriomedico.editdirectorio', compact('post'));
}
```

Vista:

```
Route::get('directorio/{directorio}', enter code here'DirectorioDoctorControler@edit')->name('admin.directoriomedico.editdirectorio');
```

Comment: ¿Con qué fin hacer esto? Todo se podría hacer en el mismo método.

Comment: requerimiento quieren registrar primero el nombre y despues los datos en el formulario de edit que al mismo tiempo sirva para actualizar datos

Comment: ¿Por qué no hacerlo simplemente como está actualmente en el método store? ahí ya estás llamando la vista de edición.

Comment: tienes razon mejor asi muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que no estas comprendiendo los conceptos básicos de MVC. Lo que pones como vista, no lo es. Es tu route, mas allá de esto, no tiene sentido moverte de ese modo entre las acciones.  Me parece que lo que estas queriendo hacer es un redirect. 
Entonces, tienendo en cuenta tu ruta al controlador DirectorioDoctorControler y apuntando a la acción edit:

```
Route::get('directorio/{directorio}', enter code here'DirectorioDoctorControler@edit')->name('admin.directoriomedico.editdirectorio');
```

En tu caso sería algo asi:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['nombre' => 'required', ]);
    $post = DirectorioDoctor::create([
        'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
    ]);
    error_log($post);
    //hacemos un redirect a edit.
   return redirect()->action('DirectorioDoctorControler@edit', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Comment: Lo puse de la manera que indicas y sigue sin obtener los datos en el metodo edit el log de store si los trae y los manda al parecer el problema es al recibir

Comment: estas seguro que está pasando la validación?